# Ambiguous method call navigation

Tags: android

using Android with Java I am getting the following error:

> Ambiguous method call. Both navigateup (NavController, DrawerLayout)
>   in NavigationUI and navigateUp (NavController, AppBarConfiguration) 
>   in NavigationUI match

trying to use this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, null);
}
```

I have no idea what I can do to resolve this, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Cast the null into the version you want to use.  The compiler isn't sure which to call, the cast will tell it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing in null, you don't need `NavigationUI` at all. Just call `navigateUp` on `NavController` itself:

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    return navController.navigateUp();
}
```